# How to add classnames from less with webpack and react?

Tags: reactjs, less, classname

I have a webpack configuration that uses less-loader, css-loader, and style-loader. When I import less file into my component file, the css is visible in chrome's devTools, but the classname is not.

I have google'd for a couple of hours and can't seem to find anything that can explain this. I know I am suppose to use this.props.className, but I am not sure how the className gets propagated. I have also tried using static strings for the className.

Here is my webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'less-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppBar} from '@material-ui/core';
import '../styles/layout.less';

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppBar className='header'></AppBar>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

I expect the className to be header, but it doesn't show any class names i provide. It only happens with Material-UI components.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer, recently had similar problem with 'antd' library and theme modification using less files. I had to split my webpack configuration into two parties (for node_modules and for resources) as follow:

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJs
        },
        {
            loader: "less-loader",  // compiles Less to CSS
            options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    ],
},
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJs
            options: { 
                modules: true
            } 
        },
        {
            loader: "less-loader",  // compiles Less to CSS
            options: {
                javascriptEnabled: true
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

Hope that helps.